# xlwings and sqlalchemy issues when using Excel with Visual Basic

Tags: python, excel, vba, sqlalchemy, xlwings

I have downloaded and installed all required programs assuming python+pandas are already installed. After installing the xlwings and sqlalchemy, according to the tutorial that I was working with, it says xlwings and Module1 are should appear in the Visual Basic, but this is not happening at all. What am I doing wrong here?

There is no problem in the Excel, but after opening the Visual Basic, I cannot seem to see the xlwings and Module1 at all:

[image]

[image]

The original tutorial got everything:

[image]